# Agile team management strategy for small projects

Tags: agile, team-management, pm-software, cost-management

I would like to thank StackExchange - Project Management group for providing me with full support and guidance to move forward in my career path. I'm now a Project Manager and a Junior web and software developer. I'm working as a freelancer for about a month.

I'm currently working on a software and a website. The project is small in nature (for a start), and so I've chosen Agile methodology. I develop prototypes with my partner and provide a weekly status meeting to the client (who is also an analyst).

I'm having conflicts with my partner because he is very immature and irresponsible. Also, his development skills are very primitive. The output produced doesn't actually satisfy me at all. And I cannot present a prototype that doesn't meet the required quality.

Due to that, I'm having trouble managing the project. He rarely obeys my advises. Also, during requirement analysis and design, he doesn't pay attention and he relies fully on me. He expects me to write the summary for him.

Then when I deny with a strong reason that "Why didn't you question the client when you didn't understand/missed out," he comments that I'm showing attitude towards work and I want to acquire the most percentage of share.

Basically the team annexure is stated based on the work effort produced to bring out the quality of the deliverable. He thinks that I want more work so that I get the most share. I've discussed this matter with him that it's not true, but he doesn't listen.

It's very difficult for me to handle these problems. How do I make him understand? I'm very annoyed and fed up with his childish behavior. Sometimes I feel like quitting.

Comment: Hi Deepz. Sounds like a tough situation but I think this question might be better suited to workplace.stackexchange.com rather than PMSE.

Comment: I posted in workplace but they closed my question.

Comment: This is a very localized question about your conflict with your partner. I think if you removed all the accusations and name calling and restricted the question to only the issues that relate to project managment, the question might be salvageable.

Comment: Hehe, I was typing with fury..that's why...I apologize for any irrelevant behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This still seems like a better fit for workplace.stackexchange.com but in the interests of helping you out I think the answer is pretty simple - learn what you can from this experience and then move on. You probably aren't going to change this person through PM alone. But you could try some of these approaches first:

- If the person you are having trouble with has a line manager then you
  may need to talk to them about performance. If their work is no good
  that's a major problem. Maybe they need more training or maybe the
  company has taken on a project that it simply can't deliver with the
  skills it currently has available.
- Clarify what is expected of you as a PM with management. Is it your job to collect requirements? Are you meant to be scheduling work for your colleague? You need to be clear on where lines of authority and responsibility lie.
- Clarify who is responsible for quality control. Is it just you who isn't happy with the quality or is it the client? If it's the client then that's a big problem. If it's just you then you can still push for quality improvements but only if you can agree who is responsible for setting standards.
- Spend some time explaining the benefits of agile to your colleague and other internal stakeholders. If it's an approach they are unfamiliar with then this might be part of the problem. If they're more used to a command and control style of management the personal responsibility element of agile may actually be quite intimidating.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've clarified everything in the annexure, that includes roles and responsibilities. From your approaches, I've missed out explaining Agile and Setting standards. I'll surely do that in the next meeting. Thanks once again.

Comment: No problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use SCRUM methodology with small sprints (like 10 working days) for make possible review the working progress by Product Owner soon as possible and mature the team with daily meetings.

Find a QA Analist for test the product before the sprint retrospective and find the bugs and issues caused by your partner. You also can turn someone, but not the involved developers, as QA Analists for your project. Measure time for tests and bug corrections before the final of the sprint.
At "lessons learned" meeting, at sprint retrospective part, is important to collect tangible activities for help define patterns and other stuff to make the others take care about the results in the next sprint.

Learn about "dialectic" for know how to talk to the problematic people without create bad conflicts, it will help you to understand their problems and them start to help them with that behavior problems. You will need to know how to ask questions to make your partner understand that his behaviour is not good, even though you know that it is not, you will need to make him understand by himself.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'll see what I can do about scrum. I've researched about dialectic, and it seems that I have to apply it when I have a talk with my colleague. Thanks for your advises.

Comment: You welcome. :)